# Equipped weapon does not appear in JSON data

Tags: unity, c#, json, scriptable-object

I'm trying to make an RPG style game with equipment using `ScriptableObject`, but whenever I equip the item, it does not register in my JSON data.

Here is the script I use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weaponItemSOs.Length; i++)
{
    if (weaponItemSOs[i].isEquiped == true)
    {
        selectedweapon = i;
    }
    else if (weaponItemSOs[i].isEquiped == false)
    {
        selectedweapon = -1;
    }
}
if(selectedweapon >= 0)
{
    power = 25 + weaponItemSOs[selectedweapon].attackBonus;
    distance = weaponItemSOs[selectedweapon].Shootdistance;
    ammo = weaponItemSOs[selectedweapon].ammo;
    currentammo = weaponItemSOs[selectedweapon].ammo;
}
else
{
    power = 25;
    distance = 20;
    ammo = 10;
    currentammo = 10;
}
PlayerGameManager.Power = power;
ShootEnemy.distanceOfRay = distance;
PlayerGameManager.Ammo = ammo;
PlayerGameManager.CurrentAmmo = currentammo;
JSONSaveSystem.SavePlayer();
```

Comment: Hint: imagine the player has equipped the weapon at index 0 in the `weaponItemSOs[]` array. What happens when your `for` loop reaches index `i = 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your equipped weapon is not the last one in the array, the one immediately after it sets `selectedweapon = -1` at the end. What you want to do is scan through the array *until* you find the equipped weapon, then *stop* searching.

Replace your for loop with something like this:

```
selectedweapon = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < weaponItemSOs.Length; i++)
{
    if (weaponItemSOs[i].isEquiped)
    {
        selectedweapon = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
selectedWeapon = System.Array.FindIndex(weaponItemSOs, weapon => weapon.isEquipped);
```